# SpriteKit create pulse action for SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction, skshapenode

I am currently trying to create an SKShapeNode with a pulsing effect SKAction seen here:
[Pulsing Shape Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKTNT.gif)

At the moment, this is a parent node containing two nodes: one for the main body of the shape and one for the outline shape which fades out. As a result, the parent node is being recognised upon touch with bounds extending to the 'outline' child node.

Is there an alternative way of creating the pulsing-outline effect I want without having to create separate nodes? i.e. as an SKAction
Or perhaps, is there a way to constrain the size of the containing node to the main shape body and still be able to see the outline effect?

Comment: I am not aware of anything that can do what you are asking.  You have more than just an outline, you literally have 2 different shapes happening, (A hollowed out star, and a smaller star on the inside). This will require 2 nodes.  Now if I were you,  make your smaller child the one that has the `userInteractionEnabled`, not the parent node. and if you need the touch code inside the parent, just call parent touch method from the child